# Storage Transaction Profiler for Windows Azure Web Deploy Accelerator

Tags: azure

I've recently begun using the [Web Deployment Accelerator](http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deploying%20the%20Web%20Host%20to%20Windows%20Azure) for my Windows Azure account. It is providing an immediate return in time saved and is an excellent offering.

However since "everything" is now stored to Azure Storage rather to the regular E:Drive I am immediately seeing a cost consequence for using the tool.

In one day I have racked up a mighty 4 cent NZD charge. In order to do that I had to burn through about 80,000 storage transactions and frankly i cant figure where they all went.

I uploaded 6 sites that are very small wouldn't have more than 300 files each. So I'm wondering:

a. is there is a profiling tool for the Web Deployment Accelerator that will allow me to see where and how 80,000 storage transactions were used for such a small offering.  Is it storage transaction intensive tool? Has any cost analysis been carried out in terms of how this tool operates? Has it been optimised with cost in mind?

b. If I'm using this tool do i pay for 2 storage transactions per http request to a site? As since the tool now writes the web server logs to table storage, that would be one storage request to pull the http request resource (img, script, etc) and a storage request to write the log entry as well would it not?

I'm not concerned about current charges I 'm concerned about the future if i start rolling all my hosted business into the cloud. I mean Im now being charged even just to "look" at my data right? If i list the contents of a storage folder using a tool like [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) that's x number of storage transactions where x = number of files in the folder?

Comment: I suggest you use accelerator for your development, but switch to a traditional deploy for your live environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of a 3rd-party profiler tool, but Windows Azure Storage logging and metrics will give you very detailed info regarding both individual accesses and hourly rollups. It's pretty straightforward to enable, and the November 2011 SDK includes support for the API calls required for enabling. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343268.aspx) for an overview of what's offered for metrics and logging.

My team worked with Fullscale180 to build a storage library, [Azure Store XRay](http://azurestorexray.codeplex.com/), to demonstrate how to enable and query storage metrics and logging. Note: This was published before the SDK had logging and metrics support, so it uses the REST API calls instead. But that won't impact you if you try to use the library.

You can also look at another code demo, [Cloud Ninja](http://cloudninja.codeplex.com/), which calls the XRay library for its metrics display (see [here](http://www.thecloudninja.com/Operations/StorageMetrics) for running demo).

Regarding querying storage for objects in blob containers: that's not a 1:1 transaction:file scenario. You can specify the maximum number of blobs to return when listing items in a container. It's possible that all blobs are returned in one transaction. Of course, if you then grab each blob, each of these will be at least one transaction (depending on blob size). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) for details about listing blobs.